How to preserve the original colors of icons in a tabbed page with bottom placement in .NET MAUI 8
In my tabbed page in .NET MAUI 8, the colors of the icons change based on the bottom placement of the tabbed page. I even attempted to adjust this in C#, but it didn't make any difference.
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LacosLiterarios.Views"
             x:Class="LacosLiterarios.Views.Tabdemo"
             Title="Minha TabbedPage"\>
<TabbedPage\>

public Tabdemo()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new TabbedViewModel();

    // Configura o ToolbarPlacement para Android
    this.On<Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.Android>()
        .SetToolbarPlacement(ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);
    
    // Obtém a ViewModel
    var viewModel = (TabbedViewModel)BindingContext;
    
    // Adiciona dinamicamente as ContentPages que envolvem os ContentViews
    foreach (var page in viewModel.TabPages)
    {
        this.Children.Add(page); // Adiciona cada aba
    }
}


Have you tried using SelectedTabColor and UnselectedTabColor to customize the color of the icon?

Yes, but my icons have more than one color, and it seems like they become transparent.

Well I can reproduce this issue that the icon is colored with a default tint color, just like shell Tabbar.
